# Replace text grabbed from Wikipedia

Tags: php, regex

I grab some text from wikipedia and there's a tricky part. In some articles there is this(ignore bad formatting):

```
 (pron.: /Ã‹ÂŒhjuÃ‹Â Ã‹ÂˆlÃ‰Â’ri/)
```

I need this gone; however there might be useful data in this way:

```
(pron.: /ˈliːsə ˈɛdəlstiːn/; born May 21, 1966)
```

I have noticed that it ends with "/" or "/;" and it starts with pron.:

I have tried and tried, but miserably failed. Is there any regex master to help me out there?

(per request) the best I could get working is to replace the parentheses 
s = s.replace(/(.*?)/, ' ');

Comment: "I have tried and tried" - tried what exactly? Include your best attempt in your question and you'll likely get a much better response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$str = "(pron.: /Ã‹ÂŒhjuÃ‹Â Ã‹ÂˆlÃ‰Â’ri/)";    
$a = preg_replace('#\/(.*?)\/#','',$str);        
var_dump($a);
```

And after this if you want to remove  the `pron.:`, use `str_replace`.

## Output

```
string(9) "(pron.: )"
```

## Codepad

Comment: That was quick. I can either feel stupid or gracious you are so good. Maybe both.